# Livewire Component doesn't redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have written a test Livewire component to redirect the page for click event of a button. My Livewire/TestRedirectComponent:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TestRedirectComponent extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test-redirect-component');
    }

    public function goToPage()
    {
        return redirect()->route('web.test');
    }
}
```

and my livewire/test-redirect-component.blade.php:

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="goToPage" class="btn btn-primary">Test</button>
</div>
```

Button is shown but no action on clicking. Please tell me if I missed something.
I am using Laravel 9 and newest Laravel Jetstream with Livewire installed.

Comment: Are you missing a closing div tag?

Comment: Sorry! Just my mistake when posting. I have the close div in my code. I fixed that in my post.

Answer (score 2):

The Issue is with eager loading not livewire!
The eager loading of relationships was causing a circular reference, so the server stopped responding.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your Livewire method is working is to simply output anything first like dd(). e.g.

```
    public function goToPage()
    {
        dd('I clicked Test button'); // this should open up the debugging black screen in your browser
    }
```

Now if it doesn't work, carefully check your browser console logs  and take a look at errors if there are any and update your post.

Update:
I notice a typo in your code, you should complete the button tag, as Livewire may not be able to properly read it.

```
Missing > symbol at the button end tag
<button>...</button <-- here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was too amateur to check if I included the Livewire assets. I fixed it.